# Collation issue after update (KB3072779) of SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, collation, windows-server

If found the following error while starting my SQL Server 2012 instance, after the update KB3072779 performed by Windows Update (Windows Server 2012 Foundation).

```
Creating procedure sp_sqlagent_get_perf_counters...
2016-11-14 12:09:07.84 spid5s      Error: 468, Severity: 16, State: 9.
2016-11-14 12:09:07.84 spid5s      Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CS_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
```

So now I'm unable to start the SQL Server instance. I managed to run it with `-t902` and perform some queries.

I did check the following:

```
select serverproperty('collation')
```

which returned:

```
Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

also

```
select name, collation_name from sys.databases
```

which returned:

```
master  Latin1_General_CI_AS
tempdb  Latin1_General_CI_AS
model   Latin1_General_CI_AS
msdb    Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

From what I've read so far, system databases must have the same collation as the server. What I'm not aware of is what happened here and what should I do now.

Did this update change the server collation?

What can I do now to run my instance normally?

===========================

**EDIT**: I finally arrive to solve the problem by following the steps described in one of the links posted by @hot2use

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3519/changing-sql-server-collation-after-installation

Comment: if the server collation has been changed after SP installation, you could try to reset the original one.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go and look at the setup.log files for the Service Pack 3 Upgrade. They should be found here:

> Each execution of Setup creates log files are created with a new timestamped log folder at %programfiles%\MicrosoftSQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\. The time-stamped log folder name format is YYYYMMDD_hhmmss. When Setup is run in an unattended mode, the logs are created at % temp%\sqlsetup*.log. All files in the logs folder are archived into the Log*.cab file in their respective log folder.

More information can be found here: [View and Read SQL Server Setup Log Files (Microsoft)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702(v=sql.120).aspx)

This might provide you with information on what happened.

If you feel like rebuilding you SQL Server instance with the correct collation, then you could try the solution here:

[How to change server level collation for a SQL Server Instance](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2901/how-to-change-server-level-collation-for-a-sql-server-instance/)

There are slight variations of above post involving re-installing the system databases and or just modifying some objects:

- [Changing SQL Server Collation After Installation](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3519/changing-sql-server-collation-after-installation/)
- [Script and Alter SQL Server Database Objects with PowerShell to Correct Collation Issues](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3578/script-and-alter-sql-server-database-objects-with-powershell-to-correct-collation-issues/)

It's not highly recommended and is best tested in a non-productive environment first. Currently there are no documented cases of the collation being changed during the setup of a service pack on SQL Server. If you don't find any information in the setup logs, then I would try and contact Microsoft and open a case/ticket.

Comment: I changed the whole server collation and the problem was fixed, thank you.

Comment: @Petaflop and hot2use: if anyone is interested in what the `sqlservr.exe -q` option does (it's the subject of the "Changing SQL Server Collation After Installation" link), I have documented it here: [Changing the Collation of the Instance, the Databases, and All Columns in All User Databases: What Could Possibly Go Wrong?](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/06/11/changing-the-collation-of-the-instance-and-all-columns-across-all-user-databases-what-could-possibly-go-wrong/).